# replace is.na() in ifelse with "== NA"

Tags: r, compare, na

```
exam$math <- ifelse(is.na(exam$math), 55, exam$math)
```

I wanted to change this like following:

```
exam$math <- ifelse(exam$math == NA, 55, exam$math)
```

And it seems that all values on math were changed to `NA`!! lol
I thought that `=` is for assignment and `==` is for comparing.
I can't understand what's wrong above. Please help!

Comment: For testing whether something is `NA` use `is.na(exam$math)`. A comparison with `==` and `NA` always yields `NA`

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `ifelse` for that. You can vectorize by using `is.na()` for subsetting:

```
exam <- data.frame(math = c(1,1,2,3,NA,NA))

exam$math[is.na(exam$math)] <- 55
exam

#   math
# 1    1
# 2    1
# 3    2
# 4    3
# 5   55
# 6   55
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also replace NA values with `dplyr::coalesce`, just as you might in SQL:

```
exam$math <- coalesce(exam$math, 55)
```